# add a new record on a popup and refresh parent with results using Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am building a page with a button which opens a popup and allows to create a new record in MySQL table. Now I would like to refresh part of the parent page with summary results after the popup window closed. Could you please let me know if there are any examples or sample code? I gooled but couldn't find any example. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any JS lib?

Assuming you are using jQuery + jQuery UI for popup, you can look at [jQuery UI modal form example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) (one note - there is no ajax used, but it's fairly simple to do so).

Idea is simple, bind to `onClose` popup event, serialize form, submit, and insert recived data into page content.

Comment: Yes, I am considering JQuery. Is it possible to save part of my web page without opening the new window? After save I need to show the summary result.

Comment: What do you mean, by 'save part of web page'? Simplifying a little, ajax is like normal request, but without page refresh - so you can prepare data to send with JS, make request, and do with received data whatever you want. There are plenty of examples. Look for `post` and `ajax` methods from jQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to call javascript function of parent which will change a particular div based upon your requirement..